# Eclipse is showing syhnchronization issue while analysing with sonar eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have analysed a project using sonar runner .Below is my sonar-project.properties content

```
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=sonar-runner
sonar.projectName=xyz
sonar.projectVersion=2.0.1

# Comma-separated paths to directories with sources (required)
sonar.sources=/home/xyz/abc

# Language
sonar.language=java

# Encoding of the source files
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Now I've installed sonar eclipse plugin and associated the project analysed in eclipse . However Sonar eclipse plugin is showing the follwing error

```
Error during issue query org.sonar.wsclient.issue.IssueQuery@7ba66ed0
Error during issue query org.sonar.wsclient.issue.IssueQuery@7ba66ed0
```

What exactly am I missing?

UPDATE below is the error logged by eclipse

```
org.sonar.ide.eclipse.wsclient.SonarWSClientException: Error during issue query org.sonar.wsclient.issue.IssueQuery@55b82685
    at org.sonar.ide.eclipse.wsclient.internal.SonarWSClientFacade.findIssues(SonarWSClientFacade.java:194)
    at org.sonar.ide.eclipse.wsclient.internal.SonarWSClientFacade.getRemoteIssuesRecursively(SonarWSClientFacade.java:170)
    at org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core.internal.remote.RemoteSourceCode.getRemoteIssuesRecursively(RemoteSourceCode.java:122)
    at org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.SynchronizeAllIssuesJob.doRefreshIssues(SynchronizeAllIssuesJob.java:136)
    at org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.SynchronizeAllIssuesJob.fetchRemoteIssues(SynchronizeAllIssuesJob.java:125)
    at org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.SynchronizeAllIssuesJob.run(SynchronizeAllIssuesJob.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: org.sonar.wsclient.base.HttpException: Error 404 on http://10.13.212.2:9000/api/issues/search?pageSize=-1&componentRoots=:esewa-kernel&pageIndex=1
    at org.sonar.wsclient.internal.HttpRequestFactory.execute(HttpRequestFactory.java:135)
    at org.sonar.wsclient.internal.HttpRequestFactory.get(HttpRequestFactory.java:121)
    at org.sonar.wsclient.issue.internal.DefaultIssueClient.find(DefaultIssueClient.java:48)
    at org.sonar.ide.eclipse.wsclient.internal.SonarWSClientFacade.findIssues(SonarWSClientFacade.java:190)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: What are your versions of SonarQube, SonarQube Eclipse plugin, Eclipse?

Comment: I have the same issue with SonarQube Plugin version3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE and Sonar Server version 3.5.1. Is there some more info about this?